# How to get position of last letter in a string in php?

Tags: php, string, search

Example of a string: `"Some text.....!!!!!!!!?????"`

Using PHP how would I get the position of the last letter (or even alphanum character) which in this example is the letter `t`?

Comment: How do you define "letter"? Is `é` a letter? `ε`? `ت`? `戊`?

Comment: A solution that would work just for the basic ascii a-z letters would be good enough, although one which would take into account european language chars (german, french) would be ideal.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) with the [regular expression `\p{L}` to find all Unicode letters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode). With the additional flag *PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE* you get also the offsets:

```
$str = "Some text.....!!!!!!!!?????";
if (preg_match_all('/\p{L}/u', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) > 0) {
    $lastMatch = $matches[0][count($matches[0])-1];
    echo 'last letter: '.$lastMatch[0].' at '.$lastMatch[1];
} else {
    echo 'no letters found';
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `/(\pL)\PL*$/u` (with `preg_match`) to save dragging out each and every letter. Either that, or `array_slice($matches[0], -1)` to save counting the number of letters.

Comment: This worked well.  One suggestion...    $lastMatch = end($match[0]);

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = "Some text.....!!!!!!!!embedded?????";

$words = str_word_count($s,2);
$lastLetterPos = array_pop(array_keys($words)) + strlen(array_pop($words)) - 1;
echo $lastLetterPos;
```

If you want to allow for alphanum rather than just alpha:

```
$s = "Some text.....!!!!!!!!embedded21?????";

$words = str_word_count($s,2,'0123456789');
$lastLetterPos = array_pop(array_keys($words)) + strlen(array_pop($words)) - 1;
echo $lastLetterPos;
```

To add other characters as valid:

```
$s = "Some text.....!!!!!!!!embedded!!à?????"; 

$words = str_word_count($s,2,'0123456789ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ'); 
$lastLetterPos = array_pop(array_keys($words)) + strlen(array_pop($words)) - 1; 
echo $lastLetterPos;
```

Answer (score 1):

try substr() ;)

echo substr('abcdef', -1, 1);

Comment: substr() doesn't differentiate between alphanumerics and other characters, nor does it return the position, but the character itself

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you consider a letter, and what you want to do with `"Some!!!???text???!!!"` for example:

The naive solution would be to iterate from the last position in the string to find the first character you want to keep, then return that. (Or iterate from the beginning to find the first character you want to stop at, then return the one before it.)

Or you can use a regex to match what you want to keep, then take the last match. (Or use a regex replace to remove what you don't want to keep, then take the last character.)

Answer (score 0):

Naive:

```
<?php
    $s = "Some text.....!!!!!!!!?????";
    $ary = str_split($s);
    $position = 0;
    $last = 0;
    foreach ($ary as $char) {
        if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $char)) {
            $last = $position;
        }
        $position += 1;
    }
    echo $last;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str    = '"Some text.....!!!!!!!!?????"';
$last   = -1;

foreach(range('a', 'z') as $letter)
{
    $last = max($last, strripos($str, $letter));
}

echo "$last\n"; // 9

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and straight-forward O(n) algorithm.

From the manual for `ctype_alpha()`:

> In the standard C locale letters are
>   just [A-Za-z]

If you need a different locale, you should abstract the function that determines if a character is alpha or not. That way you can keep this algorithm and adapt to varying languages.

```
function lastAlphaPosition($string) {
    $lastIndex = strlen($string)-1;
    for ($i = $lastIndex; $i > 0; --$i) {
        if (ctype_alpha($string[$i])) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

$testString = 'Some text.....!!!!!!!!?????';
$lastAlphaPos = lastAlphaPosition($testString);

if ($lastAlphaPos !== -1) {
    echo $testString[$lastAlphaPos];
} else {
    echo 'No alpha characters found.';
}
```